# Parse array objects using blob

Tags: javascript, arrays, blob

I manage to get this work but how to actually make it this happen when the variable actually is an array of multiple objects which you can write to each lines with blob?

```
var line1 = "firstline";
var line2 = "secondline";
var blob = new Blob([line1 + "\r\n", line2], {type: "application/txt"});

var url  = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

var a = document.createElement('a');
a.download    = "test.txt";
a.href        = url;
a.textContent = "Download test.txt";

document.getElementById('test').appendChild(a);
```

Comment: *"the variable actually is an array"* - what is *"the variable"* referencing here? There are a lot of variables there

Comment: sorry, I've find the solution already thanks ^^

Comment: In that case, it might be a good idea to provided an answer to your own question (you can do that). Maybe someday someone is going to have a similar problem and it'll be helpful for him to see how you handled it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well sorry, this is the answer, which is pretty silly for me. When the variable is an array of objects simply use join() to add lines breaks. So the output will nicely become text file with all array objects appear on new lines.

```
var arr = ['firstline', 'secondline', 'thirdline'];
var lineConcat = arr.join("\r\n");
var blob = new Blob([lineConcat], {type: "application/txt"});
```